# Edit review page: looks like all tags gone

Tags: feature-request, tags, design, review, diff

No big deal, but here with the side by side display, a **quick** look gives the false impression that all the tags were removed in the new version.
[image: tags only on left]

So perhaps it would be best to repeat them anyway, in the right column. Or center them so they don't appear to be only in the left column.

Furthermore, the original poster should be moved from the right to the left, and the new poster should be moved from the left to the right, yes, even if there is the `<HR>` bar.